# "Submit Query" keeps showing up for image_submit_tag form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I keep getting the message "Submit Query" on top of my image when I use image_submit_tag. I want to get rid of this. The image and hover image show up correctly, though.

```
<div class="action">
<%= image_submit_tag "", :class => "acctSubmit" %>
</div>
```

Here is my css for the class:

```
  .acctSubmit{
      display: block;
      background: url('createaccount_button.png') no-repeat 0 0;
      height: 43px;
      width: 197px;
   }

  .acctSubmit:hover {
     background-position: 0 -43px;
   }
```

Let me know if I can provide anything else!

Comment: I was able to come up with a short fix by creating a 1x1px transparent image (empty.png) and then changing the code to `<%= image_submit_tag "empty.png", :class => "acctSubmit" %>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not use a [`button_tag`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper.html#method-i-button_tag) instead and then style the `<button>` as needed? You're seeing  the usual "missing image" text because you're using an `<img>` tag without a `src` attribute, a properly styled `<button>` would be a better choice:

```
<%= button_tag '', :class => 'acctSubmit' %>
```

Your existing CSS should work fine but you might need some adjustments to get the desired visual effect (depending on what sort of CSS resetting you're doing).

Comment: I forgot to mention that this is for a form (specifically for creating new users). I'll try this out!

Comment: @hyngyn: `button_tag` produces `<button type="submit">` by default so it will submit the form just like an `image_submit_tag` or `submit_tag` would.

Comment: Thanks! Exactly what I was looking for. I appreciate the help, mu is too short!

Comment: Putting the dimensions inline removed the text for me, but this solution is more elegant.  <%= image_submit_tag '', :class => "highlite", :style => "width:43px;height:197px" %>

Comment: @fatfrog: Just `<img>` is not valid HTML so the browsers are free to do all sorts of strange and wonderful nonsense with it: http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec-author-view/the-img-element.html#attr-img-src

Comment: @mu is too short I agree, when I said this is more elegant, I meant your answer, not the code I pasted ;)

Comment: @fatfrog: That's what I thought :) The validity was aimed at "removed the text for me".